# Add restriction to SharePoint 2013 Image gallery to upload images only

Tags: sharepoint-server

My Image Gallery can upload ppt file and any other type of file. how can I restrict it for images file only.

I tried View but helps in filtering. I want to restric user to not even upload any file other than images

Comment: I don't think it's possible OOTB. You could write an EventReceiver and restrict the file-type in the ItemAdding-Event.